# How to create High Quality PDF in 2021 without Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: image, pdf, ms-word, office365

So I've spent the last 4 hours trying to find a way to convert this `word document` into a `pdf` that does not destroy the image quality:

https://easyupload.io/ilfsh7

[image]

1. Save as `pdf`:

[image]

Background color is lost and image quality is bad:

[image]

2. Print as pdf:

[image]

Page size is lost and image quality is a bit better but still bad and full of artifacts:

[image]

3. [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/645657/export-word-document-with-high-resolution-png-to-pdf) says that using `pdfcreator` is a good solution but it resulted in once again the loss of the page size information. The image quality was better but not good enough. I need it sharp enough for a `label print`.
4. Another thread showed how you can add options in the `registry`. Basically change the `dpi` during the conversion. As far as I can tell it did not change a thing. Image quality was still insufficient.

Do I have to buy `Adobe Acrobat` just to get a good image quality in my `pdfs`?

Comment: This question is not about programming at all. Anyway, there are millions of ways to create high-quality PDFs, your problem is that you use Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Online showcase their Word Plugin, so if you want to use similar offline for privacy then Just use their plugin to export from Word.

WordPad can be Command Line scripted to convert a docX to PDF but as you see will use the core content and can not respect customised formating such as the background.

[image]

WordPad can actually have a background colour but then again is not good with transparent images
[image]

However the point of this visual comment, is that scripting **any other Word replacement such as LibreOffice** should perform even better for personal usage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So apparently `Adobe` is offering a free [Online Conversion Tool](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/word-to-pdf.html) which produces the best results so far. Although there are still some artifacts, the quality seems to be the best:

[image]

Edit: So adobe lets you convert 2 or so pdfs until it forces you to make a subscribtion. But I found an even better online converter that seems to produce `pdfs` with perfect quality:

[pdf.online](https://pdf.online/word-to-pdf)

[image]